# What is the correct way to install dronekit on windows and ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dronekit-python, dronekit, python-install

I am new in this. I've been having trouble installing dronekit for the past few days.

I followed one of the tutorials on YouTube where on Windows using python version 3.6.0 I managed to install dronekit. For ubuntu with version 20.04 and python version 2.7 I tried to install dronekit, dronekit-sitl and mavproxy with a command like this `pip install dronekit dronekit-sitl mavproxy`
The result was that it succeeded in installing dronekit but when I checked by typing `python` then `import dronekit` it didn't work.
Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recently last call):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/home/linda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dronekit/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
     from pymavlink. dialects. v10 import ardupilotmega
   File "/home/linda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymavlink/dialects/v10/ardupilotmega.py", line 56
     def __init__(self, buf: Optional[Sequence[int]] = None) -> None:
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I checked the dronekit version on Ubuntu, it was already installed and the result was like this

```
Name: dronekit
Version: 2.9.2
Summary: Developer Tools for Drones.
Home-page: https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python
Author: 3D Robotics
Author-email: tim@3drobotics.com, kevinh@geeksville.com
License: apache
Location: /home/linda/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: monotonic, pymavlink
Required-by: dronekit-sitl
```

I tried running the python script but it doesn't work either. What exactly went wrong? I checked other tutorials but didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am quite late, but just in case anyone else stumble across this question:
Downgrading pymavlink fixes this issue. I am not sure what the latest compatible version is, but I chose 2.3.6, as this one was released shortly after the latest dronekit version. So

pip install pymavlink==2.3.6